# Is this pdo bug fixed now?

Tags: pdo, port

> Note that you can specify a port
>   number with "port=####", but this port
>   number will be ignored if the host is
>   localhost.  If you want to connect to
>   a local port other than the default,
>   use host=127.0.0.1 instead of
>   localhost.

Quoted from [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php),has anyone verified if it has been fixed?

Answer (score 25):

That isn't a bug. That is how MySQL is designed. When the host is "localhost", MySQL Unix clients use a Unix socket, AKA [Unix Domain Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), rather than a TCP/IP socket for the connection, thus the TCP port doesn't matter.

Reference: "[4.2.2. Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html)"

Comment: What about Windows?

Answer (score 6):

That's most likely not a bug in PDO, but a feature of some database client library. For example, if you use `psql` (the PostgreSQL client) to connect to *localhost*, it will use UNIX sockets, but if you use *127.0.0.1*, it will use TCP sockets and for that it obviously needs also the port number.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion you should be checking the PDO/PHP bug related pages.

But i don't think it's a bug. If you are on localhost you don't have to specify a port.